# sysjobhistory "sql_severity" codes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, msdb

Where can I find out what the different "sql_severity" codes mean in the sysjobhistory table?

Eg what does 0 mean?

I've inherited a report that excludes ones with a 0 as "0 is not a real error"?

I googled and looked at MSDN etc etc.. but no real luck.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174997%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), the `sql_severity` column is the "severity of any SQL Server error."

When this column has the value 0, that means either no message was returned (and it's therefore a magic value), or a message with severity 0 was returned. I would argue this is a bad table design, as the column does not allow `NULL`.

It's almost the same thing with the `sql_message_id` column. This column will contain 0 when no message was returned -- in this case, though, it's purely a magic value, as there's no message id 0 (run `SELECT * FROM sys.messages WHERE message_id = 0;`).

You may want to clarify the intent of the report query you've inherited, because only comparing the `sql_severity` column may not do exactly what the author thought. (Severity 0 errors being raised are undoubtedly rare, but hey, you asked.)

- If it's supposed to look for *steps that returned a message*, then it should check for `sql_message_id` > 0. As mentioned, it's completely possible that a job step can have a `sql_severity` > 0 and/or `sql_message_id` > 0 while still succeed. <sup>**</sup>
- If the query is supposed to look for *failed steps*, it should be looking at the `run_status` column instead.

<sub>** You can try this yourself by creating and running a job with a T-SQL step that simply calls `RAISERROR`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list of severity codes on MSDN here:
[Database Engine Error Severities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx)

As well zero (0) is marked as not a real error because as stated in the link above:

> Informational messages that return status information or report errors that are not severe. The Database Engine does not raise system errors with severities of 0 through 9.